# On GSuite Marketplace SDK configuration screen, what does 'Integrate With Google' do?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have configured a GSuite Marketplace App via the GSuite Marketplace SDK. Under the 'Configuration' screen there is a button called 'Integrate With Google', however there is no tooltip or hint of what that button will actually do. I'm loathe to press it as this is using a production project with live services behind it, and it's not clear what the consequences of pressing this button are.

Does anybody know what this button actually does?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish your application on the G Suite Marketplace, there are buttons 'domain install' and 'individual install' on your marketplace page. This will allow the user to install the application, and give consent.

With the 'Integrate with google' button you can test this functionality, and see how your consent screen will look like.